# How to express the variable in absolute value form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

'This is the variable which I want to express in absolute value .

```
<%= rate-32.5   =%>
```

However ,I tried

```
<%= |rate-32.5  |=%>
```

It doesn't work .

And I guess there is no this method in ruby .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this link for more details of **[.abs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-abs)** ruby method.

**abs → numeric**

Returns the absolute value of num.

```
  12.abs              #=> 12

  (-34.56).abs        #=> 34.56

  -34.56.abs          #=> 34.56
```

So you use .abs function for your solution like this 
`(rate-32.5).abs`

Answer (score 7):

Use the `abs` method:

```
(rate-32.5).abs
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby method for that:

（rate - 32.5).abs

Answer (score 2):

There is ruby method **:abs** of Fixnum or Float class. 
No need to provide '=' in '=%>' 
Use like this <%= (rate - 32.5).abs %>