# Is there a method in Ruby that checks if the difference between two Integer values is greater than a number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a method

```
def check_discrepancy(a, b)
  if a < b-5 || a > b+5
    return 'discrepancy between values!'
  end
end
```

The if statement will be true if the difference between A and B is greater than 5, the code works as intended, but I want to know if there is a different/cleaner way to do it in Ruby

Comment: You could use an absolute value instead e.g. `(a-b).abs > 5`.

Comment: That is definitely better. Thank you

Comment: in a few less keystrokes: ` ((a-b).abs > 5) ? "discrepancy between values!" : nil`

Comment: @LesNightingill `'discrepancy between values!'if(a-b).abs>5` btw your extra parentheses are not needed ruby can identify the ternary without them. Take for example `?????:??`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to express the variable in absolute value form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172262/how-to-express-the-variable-in-absolute-value-form)

Comment: `"discrepancy between values" unless a.between?(b-5, b+5)`